# Unexpected behavior in recursive function depending on Scanln error value

Tags: go, recursion

Why is it when I execute this code and input a string like "wyk" in the cmd prompt, the function `takeInput()` prints `"How old are you"` to the cmd four times before accepting a new input ?

```golang
func takeInput() {
    fmt.Println("How old are you ?")
    var age int32
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&age)
    if err != nil {
        takeInput()
        return
    }
    if age < 18 {
        fmt.Printf("sorry but, you still have %d years to go kid", 18-age)
    } else if age > 18 {
        fmt.Println("well, bottoms up then!")
    }
}

func main() {
    takeInput()
}
```

the output would look like this

```
How old are you ?
wyk
How old are you ?
How old are you ?
How old are you ?
How old are you ?
_
```

I tried adding a counter before every recursive cycle and indeed it spins a new cycle for each letter while printing the statement once per letter + 1.
Even If I input a number like 19 it would increase the counter by 2 (it won't execute `Println` though).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

1. `fmt.Scanln` scans the input. It only needs to read one single character to determine that the input is not a valid integer: `w`.
2. `fmt.Scanln` returns an error.
3. You recursively call `takeInput` again, which prints `How old are you ?`.
4. `fmt.Scanln` scans the input. It only needs to read one single character to determine that the input is not a valid integer: `y`.
5. `fmt.Scanln` returns an error.
6. You recursively call `takeInput` again, which prints `How old are you ?`.
7. `fmt.Scanln` scans the input. It only needs to read one single character to determine that the input is not a valid integer: `k`.
8. `fmt.Scanln` returns an error.
9. You recursively call `takeInput` again, which prints `How old are you ?`.

In other words, `How old are you ?` gets printed once for each invalid character in the input.

Try entering something like `a 12` or `a 20`, and you will see it more clearly:

```
How old are you ?
a 12
How old are you ?
sorry but, you still have 6 years to go kid
```

```
How old are you ?
a 20
How old are you ?
well, bottoms up then!
```

Comment: But shouldn't it take the entire entry before evaluation? Why is the output delayed if it invokes the takeInput() function on each stroke ? I don't get it.

Comment: "But shouldn't it take the entire entry before evaluation?" – Why? What would be the point in continuing to read input when it already knows that the input *cannot possibly* be a valid integer? How many valid integers do you know which start with `w`? The string could be infinitely long, after all, why should it continue reading if it already knows it cannot succeed?